# Populate XDocument from String

Tags: c#, xml, c#-3.0, linq-to-xml

I'm working on a little something and I am trying to figure out whether I can load an XDocument from a string. `XDocument.Load()` seems to take the string passed to it as a path to a physical XML file.

I want to try and bypass the step of first having to create the physical XML file and jump straight to populating the XDocument.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 588, accepted):

You can use [`XDocument.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx) for this.

Answer (score 86):

You can use [`XDocument.Parse(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx) instead of `Load(string)`.

Answer (score 43):

How about this...?

```
TextReader tr = new StringReader("<Root>Content</Root>");
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(tr);
Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

This was taken from the MSDN docs for XDocument.Load, found here...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299692.aspx

Comment: But, as pointed out in other answers, Parse is the way to do this.

Comment: Actually, Parse internally uses a StringReader.

Comment: @Samuel (and upvoters) not all TextReaders are StringReaders. This is an example of using TextReader, the fact it coincidentally shares the same reader as Parse is irrelevant.

Answer (score 24):

Try the [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx) method.