# How to parse xml and loop through it from a string?

Tags: c#, xml, string, parsing

I want parse xml by looping through it. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c) but I am not able to parse it using the Load function since it expects an URI parameter and not a string and so does LINQ to XML....Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: See [
Populate XDocument from String
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747554/populate-xdocument-from-string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XmlDocument` has a `Load` method which takes a filename, but also a `LoadXml` method which takes a string:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx

Similarly, `XDocument` has a `Load` method which takes a filename, or a `Parse` method which takes a string:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
string recentFileName = Path.Combine(folderPath, filexml);
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(recentFileName);
```

Comment: instead of using XmlDocument, use XDocument. xml-to-linq will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<root>" +
                    "<elem>some text<child/>more text</elem>" +
                    "</root>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to XDocument, we can use XElement which has Parse method to parse a xmlString.

See this code:

```
        string xmlString = @"<poi><city>stockholm</city><country>sweden</country><gpoint><lat>51.1</lat><lng>67.98</lng></gpoint></poi>";
        try
        {
            XElement x = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
            var latLng = x.Element("gpoint");

            Console.WriteLine(latLng.Element("lat").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(latLng.Element("lng").Value);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
```

Hope this helps.