# Parse HTTP response body to XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using this code to perform an HTTP request and parse the XML response:

```
using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var Obj_response = new CXML();
        var ms = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), UTF8Encoding.UTF8);   
        t = ms.ReadToEnd();// <---- This line Caused the issue    



        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CXML));    
        Obj_response = (CXML)serializer.Deserialize(ms);// <------ NOT WORKING

        return true;
    }
}
```

It shows:

> Root element is missing.

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cXML.org/schemas/cXML/1.1.009/cXML.dtd">
<cXML payloadID="Web" xml:lang="en-US" timestamp="3/7/2016 5:21:43 AM"> 
<Response>
   <Status code="200" text="OK" />
   <JobID>WebOrder 69</JobID>
</Response>
</cXML>
```

And the generated classes look like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Status")]
public class Status
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Response")]
public class Response
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Status")]
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "JobID")]
    public string JobID { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "cXML")]
public class CXML
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Response")]
    public Response Response { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "payloadID")]
    public string PayloadID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "timestamp")]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is something like that:

```
if(Obj_response.Status.code == 200)
{
    // something to happen on successful request
}
else
{
    // write the response text to log
}
```

Comment: You're trying to "read an XML attribute", which is explained in plenty of questions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933687/read-xml-attribute-using-xmldocument, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750678/getting-attribute-value-of-an-xml-document-using-c-sharp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017692/c-sharp-get-values-from-xml-attributes

Comment: They all talks about a file doc. i am talking about `GetResponseStream()` to xml

Comment: Yeah so [Populate XDocument from String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747554/populate-xdocument-from-string), [XmlDocument - load from string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929653/xmldocument-load-from-string).

Comment: No, don't find a solution.. theey all don't talk about a stream response, i did find some [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271618/how-to-convert-streamreader-data-to-xmldocument) that suppose to work, but it don't work for me, i am getting an error "{"Root element is missing."}" at this line `document.Load(stream);`

Comment: Then please edit your attempts, including the error and your research, into your question.

Comment: I have edited the question - please remove the "duplicate" .. it's not the same as the answer you suggested

Comment: Well it is, just now you're adding the information that you tried to load the XML but couldn't. The end goal and the way to get there don't change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105552/discussion-between-eran-meir-and-codecaster).

Comment: still didn't manage to do it.. help:) ?

Answer (score 0):

eventually i found the problem, the problem was with this line `t = ms.ReadToEnd();`
that cause the stream to lap through the end cause nothing to be after that.